# Rust: How to model a combined dict/array entry

Tags: rust

I'm interfacing with a C library that provides `Array`(list) and Dictionary (key + value) functionalities. Both produce and consume `Entry`s that I'm trying to model in Rust. Those `Entry`s can be of basic types, but also `Array`s or `Dictionary`s holding `Entry`s themselves. As an additional requirement, any changes to an `Entry`must be forwarded to the underlying C lib with a function call.

Available types

- String
- Integer
- Boolean
- Array (list of these types; mixing types allowed)
- Dictionary (key + value of these types; mixing allowed)

Requirements

- Build hierarchy of arbitrary combination of those types. Nesting allowed.
- Write any changes to an `Entry` back to the C lib

Taking `serde` as reference for how to model a JSON structure, I tried building those `Entry`s as an `enum`:

```rust
enum Entry {
    String(String),
    Integer(i32),
    Boolean(bool),
    Array(Vec<Entry>),
    Dict(HashMap<String, Entry>)
}
```

That works well.

Now I tried to implement my additional requirement: forward any changes to an `Entry` to the underlying C lib. So I added the reference I get from the C lib as `id`:

```rust
enum Entry {
    String{value: String, id: isize},
    Integer{value: i32, id: isize},
    Boolean{value: bool, id: isize},
    Array{value: Vec<Entry>, id: isize},
    Dict{value: HashMap<String, Entry>, id: isize}
}
```

And now I only need to make sure to call `update(id, value)` on the C lib whenever an `Entry` gets updated. So I add getter/setter methods and am done. Well, I can't do that, as I can't implement on enum variants (e.g. Entry::String).

Looks like I hit a dead end here.

Second approach: Generic structs.

```rust
trait EntryTypes {}

impl EntryTypes for String {}
impl EntryTypes for i32 {}
impl EntryTypes for bool {}

pub struct Entry<T> {
    id: isize,
    value: T,
}

trait EntryType<T> {
    fn value(&self) -> T;
    fn set_value(&mut self, value: T);
}

impl<T: EntryTypes> Entry<T> {
    fn new(value: T, id: isize) -> Self {
        Self { value, id }
    }
}
```

This works for the simple types, but I can't get it to work with `Vec` and `HashMap`:

```rust
impl EntryTypes for Vec<Box<Entry<EntryTypes>>> {}
```

```rust
The size for values of type `(dyn EntryTypes + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

How do I need to approach this?

Comment: In Rust you should define structs that are equivalent to their C counterparts; so long as they're `#[repr(C)]`, pointers to them can then be passed back and forth over the FFI.  People often use bindgen to automatically generate them (and any imported function declarations) directly from the C header files, e.g. as a part of a build script.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks for your comment, alas my question is no about FFI (I have built the connection to the C lib using bindgen), but about modeling data structures in Rust. I'd really like to understand the idiomatic way of doing this.

Comment: In that case, I think you should probably rephrase the question to remove all references to FFI since they’re distracting from your totally unrelated question?